# why my C# program can not find the *.exe file

Tags: c#

I have added one of my older C# project .exe file to resources of a new project. I wanted to run my other app with a simple button click, here is my new code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = "olderApp.exe";
  //Also I have used this line too
  //startInfo.FileName = @"Properties.Resources.olderApp.exe";
  Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

When I run the app, it would throw an exception saying that the system can not find the specified file, what did I wrong?

Comment: You have placed the `olderApp.exe` at the same place from where the code is running?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what resources are. The whole point of a resource is that they are compiled into your assembly rather than being separate files. If there's no separate file, how are you expecting `Process.Start` to find a file with that name? You should do some reading on resources.

Comment: Thanks chetan, the problem solved, I have placed it near my app .exe file

Comment: Check exe path whether it is same bin-debug folder or not  or give full path

Comment: The operating system is not capable of reading a .net resource.  It requires a file on disk.  Your user's anti-malware product appreciates that as well.

Answer (score -1):

The java file where you have this code is in the same path of 'olderPath.exe' file?

For example: if your javaFile is inside the Project path "/home/your_name/Desktop/your_project_name" and your older exe is inside a folder "Resources" that is in your Project path, so, the exe path is ""/home/your_name/Desktop/your_project_name/Resources/your_exe".

If this is your case, so, you have to change the line

```
startInfo.FileName = "olderApp.exe";
```

to

```
startInfo.FileName = "Resources/olderApp.exe";
```